# Objective-C method calling with multiple arguments

Tags: objective-c

I know the method listed below takes in 2 arguments, card and atTop. Why is atTop repeated twice? I know addCard is the name of the function and this function returns a void where card is a variable of type Card* and I know atTop is of type BOOL, but why is atTop twice?

```
- (void)addCard: (Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
```

Comment: the last `atTop` is a reference name to the value. for example it could have been `- (void)addCard: (Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)myBool;` and inside the function you would've accessed it by using `myBool`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the full name of the method is

```
- addCard:atTop:
```

So the first `atTop` is part of the function name, the second `atTop` is the name of the parameter (both are equal in this case just by conincidence, they can be different)

Comment: In Obj. C, all additional parameters must be associated with a name and a variable? For example, 
void(addCard): (Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop numCards:(int)numCards? 
I'm used to C++ where we just have one function name and put in as many variables needed. Just wanted to make sure

Comment: @baskInEminence They don't have to be the same, no.

Comment: @baskInEminence What you say ("parameters must be associated with a name and a variable") is confusing, a parameter is 'materialized' in a variable, and a variable has a name to refer to it. You can even have a function called '- addCard:::' (without 'intermediate sub-names')

Comment: It's a method, not a function (there is a difference).

Answer (score 0):

It is objective c notation.

```
(void)addCard: (Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
```

Method name (selector) -  "addCard:atTop:"

Parametr 1 type - "Card*" name - "card"

Parametr 2 type - "BOOL" name "atTop"

Return value - "void"